# GitHub Action Is Not Publishing to ghcr.io What's Wrong with Dockerfile

Tags: docker, github, dockerfile, github-actions

I have a GitHub Action that needs to publish a Dockerfile to a specific organization.
The action looks like this:

```bash
name: Docker dataeng_github_metrics

# Run workflow on tags starting with v (eg. v2, v1.2.0)
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
    paths:
      - ./data_pipelines/dataeng_github_metrics/*
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  Deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
        
      - name: Login to GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GHCR_REGISTRY_TOKEN }}
          
      - name: Build and Push Docker Image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          file: ./data_pipelines/dataeng_github_metrics/Dockerfile
          push: true # Will only build if this is not here
          tags: |
           ghcr.io/mirantis/dataeng_github_metrics:latest
```

The problem is that when I run the `Dockerfile` locally it works, but on this specific action workflow, it does not work. Instead, I get the following:

```
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/go.sum" not found: not found
Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/go.sum" not found: not found
```

And upon inspecting the `Dockerfile`:

```
###############
# CACHE IMAGE #
###############
ARG GO_IMAGE=golang:1.17.3-alpine3.14
ARG BASE_IMAGE=alpine:3.14.2

FROM ${GO_IMAGE} AS cache
# Add the keys
ARG GITHUB_ID
ENV GITHUB_ID=$GITHUB_ID
ARG GITHUB_TOKEN
ENV GITHUB_TOKEN=$GITHUB_TOKEN

# Install Git
RUN apk add git

# TODO: ENCRYPT THE GITHUB_ID AND GITHUB_TOKEN
# Make Git Configuration
RUN git config \
    --global \
    url."https://${GITHUB_ID}:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/".insteadOf \
    "https://github.com/"

WORKDIR /bin
COPY go.mod go.sum /bin/
RUN go mod download

##############
# BASE IMAGE #
##############
FROM cache AS dataeng_github_metrics
COPY . /bin
WORKDIR /bin

# Setup Git Terminal Prompt & Go Build
RUN go build .

###############
# FINAL IMAGE #
###############
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}
COPY --from=dataeng_github_metrics /bin/dataeng_github_metrics bin/
ENTRYPOINT [ "bin/dataeng_github_metrics" ]
```

It fails at the following:

```
COPY go.mod go.sum /bin/
```

This builds locally so I don't understand what the issue is.

[image]

Comment: You probably need to set a specific _context_ or change your file paths, but without a [mre] that's just a guess.

Comment: I am baffled that it will work with docker-compose but not dockerfile build even if I just do `COPY go.mod .` it won't pick up in the docker build

Comment: where is the `go.mod` file located in your project? did you try to add the `context: .` param to the build action?

Comment: The go.* files are at the same level as the Dockerfile, I did try adding the context . and that didn't seem to get me past it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to get past it, I had to add the full path to my context for the GitHub Action, I have another issue, but it's currently unrelated to the path context and not being able to find the files:

By adding in the following line, I was able to fix it by specifying the context path:

```bash
context: ./data_pipelines/dataeng_github_metrics/
```

```bash
name: Docker dataeng_github_metrics

# Run workflow on tags starting with v (eg. v2, v1.2.0)
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
    paths:
      - ./data_pipelines/dataeng_github_metrics/*
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  Deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
        
      - name: Login to GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GHCR_REGISTRY_TOKEN }}

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Build and Push Docker Image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          context: ./data_pipelines/dataeng_github_metrics/
          file: ./data_pipelines/dataeng_github_metrics/Dockerfile
          push: true # Will only build if this is not here
          tags: |
            ghcr.io/mirantis/dataeng_github_metrics:latest
```